# Excel Count Partial Match Particular Charactor

Tags: excel-formula

I have a list of names in column A2. At the end of each name is the last 2 acronyms of a state. The states are grouped into regions.

I am looking for a formula that would match and count the number of times a state is matched.

Example:
[image: Excel example]

The formula would contain all the state names in the region and then would look into the data under the Name column then count the number of matches next to Region.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Name         Region                           State   Region
123456789oh  1                                mi      1
123456789mi  1           Region 1    2        in      1
123456789wa  2           Region 2    1        oh      1
123456789hi  3           Region 3    1        mt      2
                                              or      2
                                              .   
                                              .   
                                              hi      3
```

Create a region lookup in columns (say `K:L`) as shown above. Then have a column B show the region with below formula `=VLOOKUP(RIGHT(A2,2),K:L,2,0)`. Then for `Region 1` have this formula `=COUNTIF(B:B,1)`. Similarly for others.

Comment: I've put new data in columns B,K and L. You could place them anywhere that doesn't change the structure of your spreadsheet and edit the formulae accordingly.

Comment: I like @ScottCraner 's answer, although it would be a maintenance nightmare if something goes wrong. One would be spending a bit of time in getting into grips with the formula.

Answer (score 0):

Using your setup:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDEX(H:H,MATCH(E3& "*",H:H,0),0),"*" & RIGHT($A$2:$A$5,2) & "*"))
```

One note:

SUMPRODUCT is an array type formula and as such we need to limit some of the references, specifically those that iterate.  The reference `$A$2:$A$5` is the part that iterates and as such needs to be limited to the data set and not a full column.

[image]